# Undefined index PHP con $_GET

Tags: php, mysql

estoy empezando con php y tengo este código el cual me arroja este error:

> array(0) { }
>
> Notice: Undefined index: id_tarea in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\iedan\views\modificarTarea.php on line 5

lo que trato de hacer es un formulario el cual me muestre los campos de la base de datos para modificarlos, hasta donde tengo entendido la variable se define desde el formulario pero no se donde esta el error ya que tengo otro formulario similar y funciona, gracias de antemano

el codigo es:

```
<?php 

include '../modelo/ConMod.php';
var_dump($_GET);
$id_mod = $_GET['id_tarea'];

$sql = "SELECT id_tarea, titulo, contenido FROM tareas WHERE id_tarea = '$id_mod'";

$resultado = $db->query($sql) or trigger_error($db->error);
$mostrar = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);



$query2="SELECT id_curso, nombre_curso from cursos";
$resultado2 = $db->query($query2);

$query3="SELECT id_materia,nombre_materia
              from materias";
$resultado3 = $db->query($query3);



session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["id_estudiante"])){
  if($_SESSION["id_estudiante"]["id_rol"]== 1){
    header("location:estudiante.php");
  }

  if($_SESSION["id_estudiante"]["id_rol"]== 3){
    header("location:acudiente.php");
  }


  if($_SESSION["id_estudiante"]["id_rol"]== 4){
    header("location:admin.php");
  }

}else{
header("location:index.php");
}

 ?>
```

y el formulario donde estoy tratando de llamar id_tarea es este:

```
         <form id="RegistroUsuario" action="updateTarea.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" onsubmit="return validarusu();">


          <div class="col-md-6">

           <input type="hidden" id="id_tarea" name="id_tarea" value="<?php echo $mostrar['id_tarea']; ?>">

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="identificacion">Identificacion</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ide" name="tusuario" placeholder="Identificacion"   readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar['id_tarea']; ?> ">
            </div>



           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Tarea">Tarea</label>
             <input type="text" onkeypress=" validar(event)" class="form-control" id="nom" name="ttarea" placeholder="Nombre de la tarea" value="<?php echo $mostrar['titulo']; ?>">
            </div>     
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Tarea">Contenido</label>
            <textarea id="ide" name="tdescripcion" class="textarea" placeholder="Descripción de la tarea"
                      style="width: 100%; height: 100px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"><?php echo $mostrar['contenido']; ?></textarea>
          </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button" id="registro">Modificar tarea</button> 
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

             <div class="form-group">
               <label for="Nombres">Curso</label>
              <select id="tcurso" name="tcurso" class="form-control">
                  <option value="0">Selecciona un Curso</option>
                  <?php WHILE ($row=$resultado2->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $mostrar['id_curso']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_curso']; ?></option>

                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="Nombres">Materia</label>

              <select id="tmateria" name="tmateria" class="form-control">
                  <option value="0">Selecciona un Materia</option>
                  <?php WHILE ($row=$resultado3->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row['id_materia']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_materia']; ?></option>

                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
          </div>


             </form>
```

Comment: Al inicio de tu script coloca `var_dump($_GET);` para ver lo que estás recibiendo; si no sabes interpretarlo, edita la pregunta y agrega el resultado. Por otra parte, es recomendable usar el método POST para este tipo de operaciones, tiene mayor capacidad de datos que GET y no aparecen todos en la URL.

Comment: coloque la llinea de codigo que me diste y aparece esto array(0) { } ya edite la pregunta ese es el resultado

Comment: No estoy seguro que sea eso, pero quita del formulario esta parte `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, porque se usa para poder enviar archivos y nunca por método GET. También modifica la línea que insertaste `var_dump($_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST);` y cuéntanos lo que aparece.

Comment: quite la parte de `enctype="multipart/form-data"` pero sigue igual y al agregar `var_dump($_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST);` aparece `array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { }`

Comment: Edita la pregunta y explica cómo estás haciendo el proceso, cuál script se ejecuta primero, cómo llegas hasta ahí y cómo mandas llamar el formulario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente el error ocurre porque no esta esa variable en el $_GET. Por lo que este error siempre te va a dar cuando No esté definido en la dirección -después del ? - del navegador.

Yo cuando tengo que utilizar $_GET o $_POST pregunto antes como en el siguiente IF

```
   $id_mod ="";
    if(isset($_GET['id_tarea']))
       $id_mod = $_GET['id_tarea'];

    $sql = "SELECT id_tarea, titulo, contenido FROM tareas WHERE id_tarea =".$id_mod;
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: lo siento, intente replicar el codigo pero me da error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\iedan\views\modificarTarea.php on line 8 no se como usar el isset

Comment: prueba ahora, isset es una función. Habia escrito mal el parentesis (y tampoco cerrado bien). Ahora deberia funcionar

Comment: ya me quito el error gracias, pero sigue sin mostrarme los datos en el formulario.

Comment: Estoy revisando tu código. Los WHILE los tienes en Mayusculas. No te lanza un error?

Comment: no, en minúsculas o mayúsculas funciona igual

Comment: <?php WHILE ($row=$resultado2->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $mostrar['id_curso']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_curso']; ?></option>

Comment: esos campos los muestra con normalidad el que no me muestra es el de identificación y tarea que son de la primera consulta.

Comment: Creo que te has equivocado con  las variable en el 2º While (cursos) donde tienes $mostrar que es del 1er While(tareas) . Entre el 2º y 3er While(materias)  no hay problemas porque las variables se sobreescriben.

<?php WHILE ($row=$resultado2->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $mostrar['id_curso']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_curso']; ?></option>

Comment: no, en la parte de tareas no estoy utilizando while, creo que no me estoy explicando bien, acabe de actualizra la pregunta, en mi formulario solo pongo `value="<?php echo $mostrar['titulo']; ?> "` para que me muestre el campo.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día.

En tu línea (en el HTML):

```
<input type="hidden" id="" name="id_tarea" value="<?php echo $mostrar['id_tarea']; ?>">
```

dejaste el `id` vacio; debe ser:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_tarea" name="id_tarea" value="<?php echo $mostrar['id_tarea']; ?>">
```

Te sugiero que a cada tag colocarle su valor para `id` y `name`.

Comment: ya lo puse pero sigue igual el error.

Comment: Verifica mayúsculas/minúsculas y no hay espacios. Prueba quitando el type="hidden"; usa style="display:none"; si sigue, implica que el elemento (por nombre) como lo estas referenciando no se esta recibiendo; imprime el $_GET ( print_r($_GET) ) para ver si existe ese elemento en lo que se recibe. Tienes varios input algunos de esos "debe llegar".

Answer (score 0):

Te fijaste que la consulta SQL este funcionando?

$sql = "SELECT id_tarea, titulo, contenido FROM tareas WHERE id_tarea = '$id_mod'";

Puede ser que este mal la columna.

Comment: dentro del código no funciona por la misma razón, no encuentra un valor en la variable $id_mod por que aparece como indefinida en la parte de $id_mod = $_GET['id_tarea']; pero al correr la consulta en mysql si funciona

Comment: En esta linea proba de sacar el hidden y ver si te llega bien.
<input type="hidden" id="id_tarea" name="id_tarea" value="<?php echo $mostrar['id_tarea']; ?>">